# Is it possible to get variables values chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to use variables with chrome.storage.sync.get

```
var variable = "item1";

var f = (function () {chrome.storage.sync. get ({ items: [ variable ] }, function(storage) { }) }); 
f();
```

The `items` storage value will be the variable value.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code reads `items` from storage and provides its default value as an array `[variable]`. You probably need `chrome.storage.sync.get(itemName, function(data) { console.log(data) })`. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-get).

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. Please provide more explanation as to what you are really trying to do.